# Increase in average CTR but decrease in average position in Google Search results

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, ctr

In the last few months, we have had created new content for some given pages of a hotel microsite.
Upon comparing the performance of those pages (last three months to the previous period), it shows a decrease in average position in Google Search results while the average CTR has improved. Can anyone explain the reason behind such performance? As I know higher the average CTR of a page, the better its average position in the search results. Attached are the performance screenshot of different pages.

[image: Result Metrics]
[image: The CTR improved but Avg pos decreased]
[image: Avg position decreased]

Answer (score 3):

1. The assumption that the higher the CTR, the higher the average position, is wrong.
2. CTR has a lot to do with position in the SERPs, **however**, the title and (visible) description makes a lot of differences see [summary section on this page](https://backlinko.com/google-ctr-stats).
3. A lower position doesn't necessarily mean less clicks, statistically (on average) it does, but there are a lot of exceptions.
4. The average position stat in the Google Search Console is not very accurate. I recommend you use an SEO tool, such as Ahrefs or WebCEO (Ahrefs has a lot of historical data but WebCEO is an SEO suite to track your site).

Hope this helps, and best of luck!

Comment: Thank u for your respond Eric and Tal. Will look into MOZ tool. What steps would you recommend to increase a page Avg.position apart from Backlink strategy. Kindly suggest

Comment: Mainly high quality content and good UX (not necessarily UI). High quality content, backlinks and recently an emphasis on UX are the top factors as far as I know.